# Include NULL values in Json Response

Tags: java, json

I would like to see the json response with null fields. Even if set the defalut value as null in the json schema, those fields are not getting displayed. I think, all null fields are getting filtered internally. for ex.

```
"streetAddress": {
            "line1": "2374 WATER WORKS RD"
            "line2" : null
          },
```

Currently if i don't set the line2 , it is not getting appeared in the response. Simply i am getting

```
"streetAddress": {
            "line1": "2374 WATER WORKS RD"
             }
```

## pom.xml

POJO's are generated using maven plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.11</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</sourceDirectory>
        <targetPackage>com.dnb.daas.matchplus.product.ng.schema.request</targetPackage>
        <includeJsr303Annotations>true</includeJsr303Annotations>
        <initializeCollections>false</initializeCollections>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

## Json Schema:

```
"streetAddress": {
  "id": "streetAddress",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "line1": {
      "id": "line1",
      "type": "string"                        
    },
    "line2": {                        
      "id": "line2",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false                   
}
```

Sample POJO:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "line1",
    "line2"
})
public class StreetAddress {

    @JsonProperty("line1")
    private String line1;
    @JsonProperty("line2")
    private String line2;
```

I tried putting a sysout before returning the json response and i could see the null fields are present.

[line1=2374 WATER WORKS RD,line2=AnglebracketOpen**null**AngleBracketClose]

I am using Swagger and Post Man as the rest client. In both null field are not appearing.

Comment: have you tried removing `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`?

Comment: Good spot... I tried couple of things removing the @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) also changing it to @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS). In both the case , i could see the null field in my rest client. Thank you very much.. .Can you please tell how to remove this tag or modify this to @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS) as i am using maven to automatically generate pojo's out of json schema.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Micronaut Framework then below code works

**Application.yml**

```
jackson:
  serializationInclusion: ALWAYS
```

Answer (score 0):

This maven config does the trick:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.37</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-id</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/json</sourceDirectory>
                        <targetPackage>org.jozefowicz</targetPackage>
                        <inclusionLevel>ALWAYS</inclusionLevel>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```